# Where / how to post a question that might spark debate?

Tags: discussion

I received a comment on an SO post saying basically "Oh, don't do X, it's a bad idea," with no explanation given as to *why* it was a bad idea. I was quite surprised by the comment as I thought that what I was doing was a fairly standard programming convention.

I would like to ask the question: "What is the reason for not doing X?" on SO, but I can see how that might be interpreted as subjective or argumentative, which means it wouldn't fit on SO.

My question is:

A. Is there a valid way to construct a "Can someone explain to me why you should/should not do _____ in _______ situation?" question? If so, what does it look like.

B. If there isn't a valid way to ask that question on Stack Overflow, where else might one look to find an answer to that kind of question?

Thanks!

Comment: They explained why you shouldn't. End of.

Comment: No, there was no explanation given in the comment, it was just "oh, don't do that." Hence my desire for a broader explanation.

Comment: Saw the example as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141586/application-helper-spec-test-controller-specific-output/8141662#comment-9998058 - Which states why it was unnecessary. Otherwise, they're just baiting you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this:

> Can someone explain to me why you should/should not do this in __
>   situation?

and link to your original post so that everyone can see the conversation that elicited your question.

However, in the body of your question, you should clarify that you're looking for a reason why putting an ID in the `<body>` tag might be actively harmful; i.e. will it actually break something, or is it merely an annoyance to the purists?